# API of EtherEx, give an example

Tags: exchanges, exchange-api, etherex

Please give an example how to use [EtherEx](https://github.com/etherex/etherex) API from both JavaScript and Python programs.

Where should I connect before sending a method call?

I am especially interested in `add_market` method.